# Deploy ipad app for limited devices

Tags: ios, ipad

I have developed an iPad application for particular company's staff.
How should i deploy it so that only the company staff can download this application.
If i use developer's profile, they will have to refresh the profile every 3 months.
So what is the other way?

Note: I have the device id of all the devices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your option is to get Enterprise developer certification from Apple

read more on : https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: This, if you want your client to use the app past the 3-month lifetime of adhoc builds. Otherwise, you can use adhoc as others pointed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an AdHoc build with a Distribution Certificate with all devices added to that certificate. you can find adhoc build in Xcode organizer[image]

Here select Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment

Comment: Suppose i have a developer account and i create Ad-Hoc build with distribution certificate, will that work? Or will it expire after 3 months, just like developer certificate?

Comment: No it will not expire in distribution certification. Ad-hoc build will work with 100 devices according to the developer account.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an enterprise account you can allocate specific devices,

if you dont have the enterprise account, and an adhoc doesn't cut it[ expiration date very short], you can just use a password?, that the intended users will know?

use the token of the device, and if the registered token doesn't gets recognised, show an error login in screen

Comment: I wonder if Apple would allow such an app in the store... For starters, the review team would not be able to test it.

Comment: @ranReloaded I have apps that work with this password only for interested parties, you just send the password as a comment for the review process and explain this in the message